# Using mock.patch in Python

Tags: python, mocking

How can I patch a variable used by `foo()` and which is imported from another file?

```
test file:
from f import foo

def test():
  foo()


f file:
from f2 import some_var

def foo():
  print some_var
```

Even if `some_var` in `f` file is 10, I might want it to have another value, when `foo()` is called from `test()`. How can I achieve that using `mock.patch.object`?

Answer (score 0):

Without trying it myself:

```
#test file
import f2
import mock

def test():
    with mock.patch('f2.some_var', 'your-new-value-for-somevar'):
        # your test code
```

as you are importing `some_var` using `from f2 import some_var` in your "f file" then you'll need to make sure that the patch is in place when `from f2 import some_var` runs.  I'd just use `import f2` in "f file" instead, and refer to `some_var` as `f2.some_var`.

---edit--- 
Gah, you can of course just do this in your test class:

```
#test file
import f
import mock

def test():
    with mock.patch('f.some_var', 'your-new-value-for-somevar'):
```

This will patch the value of `some_var` that has been copied into `f` by `from f2 import some_var`

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need patch.object for modifying values in the case you've given. You can just do:

test.py:

```
from f import foo
import f

f.some_var = 'test-val'

def test():
  foo()
```

Foo will then print out 'test-val' in the case you've given.

If instead you have a function that needs to be mocked, you can use patch.object as a decorator in addition to Steve's example.

test.py

```
from mock import patch
from f import foo  
import f    

@patch.object(f, 'some_fn')               
def test(some_fn_mock):     
    some_fn_mock.return_value = 'new-stuff'    
    f.foo() 


test()
```

f.py

```
from f2 import some_fn
def foo():              
    print some_fn()
```

f2.py

```
def some_fn():         
    print 'stuff'
```